# how would i implement -1 when running the code

Tags: java

code works fine but I just can't seem to be able to run the code with -1 being the only input i use to calculate the average.

```
import java.util.*;

class Bowling {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int G = 0;

        int scores = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        double highest_average = 0;
        int times = 0;
        int players = 4;

        for (int i = 1; i <= players; i++) {
            System.out.println("Player " + i);
            if (avg > highest_average)
                highest_average = avg;
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter your bowling score:");
                G = keyboard.nextInt();
                scores += G;
                times++;
            }
            while ((G != -1));
            scores += +1;
            times = times - 1;
            avg = (scores) / (times);
            System.out.printf("Average= %.2f\n", avg);
            scores = 0;
            times = 0;
            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("Highest average:" + highest_average);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample run:   So the code works fine but its just i dont know if i should use a IF statement to let -1 be calculated as the average.

```
Player 1

Enter your bowling score:

300

Enter your bowling score:

222

Enter your bowling score:

-1

Average= 261.00

Player 2

Enter your bowling score:

210

Enter your bowling score:

211

Enter your bowling score:

300

Enter your bowling score:

-1

Average= 240.00

Player 3

Enter your bowling score:

233

Enter your bowling score:

-1

Average= 233.00

Player 4

Enter your bowling score:

112

Enter your bowling score:

-1

Average= 112.00

Highest average:261.00
```

Here is another run but when -1 is inputted first

```
Player 1

Enter your bowling score:

-1 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at LabQuiz1.main(LabQuiz1.java:33)    // I keep getting this when -1 is inputted I have been thinking of using a IF statement to tell the code that if  -1 is implemented it should still calculate 0 as the average.
```

Comment: `avg = times == 0 ? 0 : (scores)/(times);`

Comment: Question what is "?" used for in this scenario?

Comment: see http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here:

```
scores += + 1;//change to scores+=1
times = times - 1; //in do while loop you increment by one and now you decrement it and hence 0
avg = (scores)/(times);//you could check for times if 0 here. and you are dividing by integer if you want accurate decimal result change denominator to decimal as well.
```

Change it to:

```
scores += 1;
times = times - 1; 
avg = times == 0? 0: (scores/(times * 1.));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using -1 as a special number to exit processing then you should use an **if** condition to not process the input as part of the calculation.

```
double highest_average=0;
int players = 4;

for(int i =1; i<=players; i++) {
  double avg = 0;
  int times = 0;
  int scores = 0;

  System.out.println("Player " + i);
  if (avg > highest_average) 
    highest_average= avg; 

  do
  {
    System.out.println("Enter your bowling score:");
    G = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(G ==-1)
      break;

    scores += G;
    times++;
  }
  while(true);   

  // remove the following lines that aren't necessary anymore
  //scores += + 1;
  //times = times - 1; 

  if(times > 0)
    avg = (scores)/(times);

  System.out.printf("Average= %.2f\n", avg);
  //scores =0; times =0; 
  System.out.println("");
}
```

If you don't want to allow negative numbers then change the **if** condition accordingly.

You can modify the **do/while** condition to be do ... while(true) since now you exit the loop on the **break** statement.

You can move the **avg**, **scores** and **times** variables to be within the **for** loop since they are only used within the scope of the for loop. Those variables get initialized to 0, instead of needing to initialize the values again at the bottom.